# How to change Object Length when Generating Database Script using PowerDesigner 16?

Tags: mysql, sap-ase, powerdesigner

I'm doing a reverse engineer of a MySQL database to pass it to a Sybase database.

When I generate the Database Script (for the Sybase database), it gives me errors because it only allows a 30 length object name. The thing is, with ASE 15.X versions, we can have object names with 250 tops.

Is it possible to change the object name length allowed?

Comment: Are the errors occuring in Powerdesigner when you generte the DDL, or in ASE when you execute the DDL?

Comment: The errors are occurring when I generate the DDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38058.1650/doc/html/rad1232021203575.html):

> The database package name and code length is limited by the maximum length
>   specified in the DBMS definition and in the naming conventions of the model
>   options.

Length is specified in the DBMS definition, which can be found at

**OBJECT > DB Package > MaxLen**

Open the DBMS editor, with Database > Edit Current DBMS
Then under Script > Objects.

Comment: I've already saw this in the docs but I don't know where this menu is located. (where is OBJECT) ?

Comment: It's `MaxLen` without space. Open the DBMS editor, with `Database > Edit Current DBMS`; then under `Script > Objects`. For a ASE 15.0, I have 9 entries for `MaxLen` (all set to 255 in my version).

Comment: Thanks @pascal, I missed that.  Updated my answer with the details.